# Xero Oauth2 PHP problems

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, xero-api

I have just completed the Oauth2 flow and it is working perfect. I am using the official PHP library but I cant get my cron jobs to update the tokens.

I am getting this error: ***Uncaught exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Required parameter not passed: "refresh_token"*** when I try to do a refresh.

The code is as follows.

```
  ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
  require '../../vendor/autoload.php';
  include '../config.php';

  // Use this class to deserialize error caught
  use XeroAPI\XeroPHP\AccountingObjectSerializer;

  $accessToken  = "**********"
  $refreshToken = "**********"
  $realID       = "**********"  

  $xeroTenantId = (string)$realID;

    $provider = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
      'clientId'                => '********************************',   
      'clientSecret'            => '******************************************',
      'refresh_token'           =>   $refreshToken,
      'urlAuthorize'            => 'https://login.xero.com/identity/connect/authorize',
      'urlAccessToken'          => 'https://identity.xero.com/connect/token',
      'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => 'https://identity.xero.com/resources'
    ]);

    $newAccessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('refresh_token', [
      'refresh_token' =>  $refreshToken
    ]);

    $config = XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setAccessToken( (string)$refreshToken );    
  
  $accountingApi = new XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Api\AccountingApi(
    new GuzzleHttp\Client(),
    $config
  );

  $assetApi = new XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Api\AssetApi(
    new GuzzleHttp\Client(),
    $config
  );  

  $identityApi = new XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Api\IdentityApi(
    new GuzzleHttp\Client(),
    $config
  );  

  $projectApi = new XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Api\ProjectApi(
    new GuzzleHttp\Client(),
    $config
  );
```

Is Anyone here that can see what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong code, should be:

```
  $newAccessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('refresh_token', [
      'refresh_token' =>  $refreshToken,
      'grant_type' => 'refresh_token'
    ]);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).